# List S3 buckets by bucket policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-policies

I have 400+ buckets in my AWS account some of which can be accessed by users using user group **dev-user-group** & **prod-user-group**. Few S3 buckets's policies are something like this

```
"aws:arn": [
     "arn:aws:sts::123XXXXX43:assumed-role/dev-user-group/*"
     "arn:aws:sts::123XXXXX43:assumed-role/prod-user-group/*"
]
```

Now, we would like to change it to the following

```
"aws:arn": [
     "arn:aws:sts::123XXXXX43:assumed-role/dev-eid/*"
     "arn:aws:sts::123XXXXX43:assumed-role/dev-p-eid/*"
     "arn:aws:sts::123XXXXX43:assumed-role/prod-eid/*"
     "arn:aws:sts::123XXXXX43:assumed-role/prod-p-eid/*"
]
```

Few buckets have only any one of accesses & few don't have any access.
We would like to automate the process for updating the bucket policies using a script such that the script need to check if **dev-user-group** & **prod-user-group** is defined in the bucket policies. If so, it should remove them & add new policies.

I hope I conveyed better. Kindly give me suggestions on this.

Comment: Try using Boto3, AWS SDK. Using this you can automate the process. Here is the link to [Boto3 AWS S3 python SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

Comment: Are you wanting to grant them access to _every_ bucket, or just a subset of the buckets? If it is a subset, how can they be identified (eg do they all have the same bucket prefix)? How are you currently granting access based on Employee ID? What is a P-EID?

Comment: @anuragal, can we filter S3 bucket based on the content in S3 bucket policies?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Not exactly. It's just for the buckets that have specific access. I updated the description please have a look. 
There is no subset & P-EID is some kind of special id just like eid.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create quick script and use the aws cli for this.

The script will first list all the buckets you have in the account `aws s3 ls` then save that list and loop over the list of buckets using this command which will output the policy as a json file:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket mybucket --query Policy --output text > policy.json
```

You can then modify the `policy.json` file as needed. Finally you can apply this modified policy back to the S3 bucket by running:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket mybucket --policy file://policy.json
```

[Source](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-policy.html#get-and-put-a-bucket-policy)

Comment: This can be useful if I only rely on policy retrieval. Since, I'm looking for updating the policies, I again have go through each & every file & update it which doesn't seem to be an automated solution.
I would be glad if there is any automation solution to list buckets filtered by bucket policies & update them.

Comment: I am not sure if there's an automated solution which you will find a tailored made, but what I mentioned is how you can go about if you create your own script to automate this. List buckets and save the list as a file> have a function that then loops over the buckets list, get the policy of each one and if it matches a certain condition, put them in a separate list, where then you have a third function to update only the policies of the target list. 

I can understand that you might be under time pressure to implement this yourself as it will probably take a few hours to write the script.

Comment: However, having said that, I would definitely agree with the other answer posted by @John-Rotenstein where he mentions using IAM policies instead as this would be the correct organisational approach to manage permissions in AWS.

Comment: I will try & figure out if we can achieve it with boto3 or will follow the above mentioned practice. get-bucket-policy>output-to-files>read-json-files>make-required-changes>put-bucket-policy.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule:

- Use an **IAM policy** to assign bucket permissions to IAM entities (eg IAM Users, IAM Roles, IAM Groups), *or*
- Use an **Amazon S3 bucket policy** to grant public access to content

It is normally much easier to grant IAM entities permission by putting the policy on that IAM entity, rather than adding permissions on each S3 bucket.

Therefore, instead of granting access via a bucket policy on 400+ buckets, you could create **add an IAM policy to the four IAM Roles** (`dev-eid`, `dev-p-eid`, `prod-eid`, `prod-p-eid`) that grants them permissions on the buckets. It would look something like:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket2",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket3",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket4",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket5",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket6",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket7",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket8"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket3/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket4/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket5/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket6/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket7/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket8/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You will likely face limitations due to the allowable size of policies, so multiple policies might be required (or it might not work at all, given you have so many buckets). A simpler method would be to reference bucket by prefix, such as:

```
"arn:aws:s3:::dev-*"
```

In this way, you can grant permission on any bucket that begins with `dev-*`, so the policy would actually be quite short (presuming that your buckets can be easily grouped in this way).

Comment: I agree with the practice. We can follow IAM policy for users yet we need to update the policies to remove existing permissions.
That's another reason, I'm looking for automation script.